# Can Qaza salat be prayed in short form?

Tags: salat, fiqh, salat-qada

I came to know that Qaza salat can be prayed or it is allowed to pray it in quicker manner by following some rules.The link is given below:

http://www.islamicacademy.org/html/Learn_Now/English/Qaza_e_Umree.htm

So, my question is, is the rules mentioned in the link correct, if it is 
then How? and if it isn't , then Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All Praise to Allah Subhan o Taala and blessings on Prophet Muhammad peace be upon him His Family and Companions

The steps mentioned in your given link is correct according to hanafi Fiqh and this fatwa is mentioned in Fatawa Razawia ,As it is stated there that All the fardh and wajibat have to be done in that missed prayer so in this way that missed  prayer could easily be performed without delaying it due to laziness or thinking to perform when one gets some free time because it would not put burden on the Nafs.It is essential to make up all the previous missed prayers so this could easily be done without skipping any Fardh or wajib of prayers.

Jabir (May Allah be pleased with him) reported:
**The Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) said, "Between a man and disbelief and paganism is the abandonment of Salat (prayer)."**
[Muslim].

Allah Swt and His Messenger knows best.