# What about Qadha prayers as a converty? (Making up missed Prayers for converts)

Tags: conversion, salat-qada

I converted one and a half years ago and at one point I calculated my missing prayers so I could offer them. I was doing, everyday two past days prayers so I was going to finish at 2019. But then a friend of mine said I'm not obligated to do so because I converted and it's like I have no sins before that. Now another friend says that I was a neglecting muslim so I have to offer the missed prayers.

I was a deist before, I believed in a 'creator' because I couldn't explain what happend/ what was there before the planets started to cool off. So I assumed there was something that started everything. Besides that, I believed in being a 'good' person because I wanted to go to heaven. But I wasn't sure of the concept of heaven. I just assumed it was there, next to hell. One day I had a dream and I started to believe. I became aware of Allah's presence. So I don't know if I'm responsible of the missing prayers or not.

Comment: Don't listen to your second friend, listen to the first one.You won't be held accountable for the prayers before reverting to Islam. Allah knows best.

Comment: A reference would be nice but thank you for answering.

Comment: @FulyaY, yea, you are right regarding the ref. / Anyhow tis a helpful question for others who... / God bless you.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

All Praise to Allah Subhanahu wa Taala and blessings on Prophet Muhammad peace be upon him His family and companions

It is an important query may Allah Swt shower more blessings on you,

> Prophet Muhammad (peace be upon him) said “Whoever forgets a prayer
>   must perform it when they remember it.”  (Bukhari)

You have to make up for the missed prayers (Fardh Salah only) after your conversion as it is obligatory to make up for the missed prayers,You have to count from that day and In Sha Allah you would be able to do it soon (See [this](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/29272/can-qaza-salat-be-prayed-in-short-form/29279#29279) to make it more easy).Check these for explanation:

http://seekershub.org/ans-blog/2012/09/04/new-converts-making-up-missed-prayers-and-praying-confirmed-sunnas/

http://seekershub.org/ans-blog/2010/04/12/making-up-missed-prayers-a-point-of-scholarly-consensus/

Allah Swt and His Messenger knows best.

Comment: Can i assume that its the same for past ramadan fastings?

Comment: Your references relate to missed prayers of Muslims not the same for converts. Your "converts" reference says that you have to make up for missed prayers after you were aware that you had to pray not for prayers before you converted. Therefore I do not know why you answer that he/she has to make up for the missed prayers???!!

Comment: @Noor Read the answer again it is mentioned that that one has to pray those prayers which were missed after conversion,Also read the links provided JazakAllah